# In condition using LINQ

Tags: linq

OK, another LINQ question.  How do I do  an "IN" condition using LINQ.  I have an IEnumerable list of myObject and want to do something like myObject.Description in('Help', 'Admin', 'Docs').  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IN in sql is equivalent is `Contains` in LINQ

```
string[] countries = new string[] { "UK", "USA", "Australia" };
var customers =
    from c in context.Customers
    where countries.Contains(c.Country)
    select c;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Contains` on a collection:

```
string[] descriptions = { "Help", "Admin", "Docs" };

var query = from foo in list
            where descriptions.Contains(foo.Description)
            select ...;
```

(For larger collections, a `HashSet<T>` might be better.)

Comment: Would a HashSet<T> work in for any provider apart from LINQ to objects?

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure about a `HashSet<T>`. Many providers allow a list or array to be used at execution time, translating into an "IN" clause in SQL. It's provider-specific though.