# C# SQL Multiple IN Selectors

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, parameters

My output query looks like:

```
select * from Calls where CallerID = "User.Name" and Endpoint in ("C,D,V") order by JoinTime desc;
```

My C# query string with parameters looks like this:

```
string SQLQuery = "select * from Calls where CallerID = @UserName and EndpointType in ({0}) order by JoinTime desc";
```

The code to add the parameters looks like this:

```
...

string[] Endpoints = new string[] {"C","D","V"}; //EXAMPLE string array
string UserNameStr = "User.Name"; //EXAMPLE string UserNameStr value

...

string[] paramNames = Endpoints.Select((s, i) => "@endpoint" + i.ToString()).ToArray();

string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);


using (cmd = new MySqlCommand((string.Format(SQL, inClause)),connection))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], Endpoints[i]);
    }
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", MySqlDbType.String).Value = UserNameStr;

MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

...
```

But what if I wanted to add another IN operator so the output query would look like this ;

```
select * from Calls where CallerID = "User.Name" and Endpoint in ("C","D","V") and ConferenceCall in ("D","C") order by JoinTime desc;
```

How do I do that? Is there some features in Linq that could be used?

Comment: You can look over here for an alternate idea.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146978/select-with-many-discrete-values-possible-in-where-clause/15147088#15147088

Comment: But even before that, check out: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: The current way you handle the IN selectors is broken and _vulnerable to sql injection attacks_ (depending on where you get the data for the individual items). Also, in standard sql, double quotes mean column names. You need to use single quotes instead for text literals.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn How do you propose passing a parameter to an `IN` clause?

Comment: Maybe you can to read that another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753006/in-condition-using-linq here is using Linq for select with Contains

Comment: [This](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/73838/) may also be useful

Comment: string[] endpoints = new string[]{ "A",") WHERE USERNAME=ADMIN --"}  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Melanie it would be _more_ useful if it weren't behind a registration wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way you do it the first time:

```
// endpoints = comma-delimited list of endpoints
// conferenceCalls = comma-delimited list of conference calls

string SQLQuery = "select * from Calls " + 
                  "where CallerID = @UserName and " + 
                  "EndpointType in ({0}) and " + 
                  "ConferenceCall in ({1}) " + 
                  "order by JoinTime desc";

cmd = new MySqlCommand((string.Format(SQL, endpoints, conferenceCalls)),connection);
```

As noted in comments, be VERY careful that you validate the strings to avoid SQL injection attacks.  There's not a direct way to pass a collection as a SQL parameter.  There are ways to do it (passing a delimited string and parsing it is the most common I've seen), but if you are in control of setting the value and validate the data then you should be fine.